# I rented a basement bachelor suite in a house, but now I remember that there is a dog upstairs in the house. Is this haram for me to rent?

Tags: dogs

I have been struggling quite a bit in my current shared accommodation. My non-Muslim roommates are dirty and listen to music (often during prayer/salah times).

So I've been looking for a bachelor suite for myself for a long time. I've just found what I feel is a very, very good deal - an affordable place in a really beautiful neighborhood. I've paid the security deposit and I plan to move in next month.

I now remember that the landlord who lives upstairs mentioned he has a small dog (i.e., not a guard or hunting dog). I am now all over the place gasping for air. I know having a pet dog in the house is prohibited and that angels don't enter homes with a pet dog. My question is, does that apply to me? I have a separate basement suite and it has a separate entrance.

I am willing to let go of the deposit and look for a new place if it is indeed haram for me, but I want to be sure. Can someone point me in the right direction. Maybe a hadith that talks about a dog living in the premises but not in the person's direct apartment?

Comment: So what's the issue? The dog is not yours and it is not in your own home!

Answer (score 1):

Huh! It's like a chain destruction, meaning If any of its link is broken the whole chain will be useless when it comes to carry something weighty. If this case had enjoined upon us as well then our life would have got stuck and we could't be able to do anything except for standing!!!  When you go out, you find people’s smoking, drinking wine, mixing with girls, fornicating, living together(couple), dating, beating their parents/wife/daughters!, these things are strictly prohibited in islam and this type of act can alone be enough for oneself to take him to Hell! well then, **does it mean that you can't go out because these guys are doing crazy things (exception for woman)?** When you go to shopping mall you find haram things in it, as soon as you spot that haram thing you run away ¿!
Listen, it's not in our capacity to **prevent all of these things, we just have to live and abide by within the barrier of islam in a right way not the way of our desire/thinking**.
Islam says keeping a dog without any necessity (e.g., for hunting, for guarding livestock and crops) is **prohibited** and **if you do so then everyday from your deeds there will be a huge amount of cutting down of deed!**

Aahadith :----

> [1] "وَحَدَّثَنِي أَبُو الطَّاهِرِ، وَحَرْمَلَةُ، قَالاَ أَخْبَرَنَا
> ابْنُ وَهْبٍ، أَخْبَرَنِي يُونُسُ، عَنِ ابْنِ، شِهَابٍ عَنْ سَعِيدِ
> بْنِ الْمُسَيَّبِ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، عَنْ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى
> الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏"‏ مَنِ اقْتَنَى كَلْبًا لَيْسَ بِكَلْبِ صَيْدٍ
> وَلاَ مَاشِيَةٍ وَلاَ أَرْضٍ فَإِنَّهُ يَنْقُصُ مِنْ أَجْرِهِ
> قِيرَاطَانِ كُلَّ يَوْمٍ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ وَلَيْسَ فِي حَدِيثِ أَبِي الطَّاهِرِ
> ‏"‏ وَلاَ أَرْضٍ ‏"‏ ‏.‏"     Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger
> (ﷺ) as saying:  He who kept a dog which is neither meant for hunting
> nor for watching the anitmals nor for watching the fields would lose
> **two qirat every day out of his reward**; and there is no mention of the fields in the hadith transmitted by Abu Tahir.
>
> [Sahih Muslim, 1575 a In-Book Reference: Book 22, Hadith 69 USC-MSA
> web (English) reference: Book 10, Hadith 3822 (deprecated numbering
> scheme)]
>
> [2] حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ بْنُ حُمَيْدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الرَّزَّاقِ،
> أَخْبَرَنَا مَعْمَرٌ، عَنِ الزُّهْرِيِّ، عَنْ أَبِي سَلَمَةَ، عَنْ
> أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏
> مَنِ اتَّخَذَ كَلْبًا إِلاَّ كَلْبَ مَاشِيَةٍ أَوْ صَيْدٍ أَوْ زَرْعٍ
> انْتَقَصَ مِنْ أَجْرِهِ كُلَّ يَوْمٍ قِيرَاطٌ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالَ
> الزُّهْرِيُّ فَذُكِرَ لاِبْنِ عُمَرَ قَوْلُ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ فَقَالَ
> يَرْحَمُ اللَّهُ أَبَا هُرَيْرَةَ كَانَ صَاحِبَ زَرْعٍ ‏.‏     Abu
> Huraira (Allah be pleased with him) reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as
> saying:  He who kept a dog except one meant for watching the herd, or
> for hunting or for watching the fields. he lost **two qirat of reward
> every day.** Zuhri said: The words of Abu Huraira (Allah be pleased
> with him) were conveyed to Ibn Umar who said: May Allah have mercy
> upon Abu Huraira; he owned a field.   [Sahih Muslim, 1575 b In-Book
> Reference: Book 22, Hadith 70 USC-MSA web (English) reference: Book
> 10, Hadith 3823 (deprecated numbering scheme)]
>
> [3] حَدَّثَنِي زُهَيْرُ بْنُ حَرْبٍ، حَدَّثَنَا إِسْمَاعِيلُ بْنُ
> إِبْرَاهِيمَ، حَدَّثَنَا هِشَامٌ الدَّسْتَوَائِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى
> بْنُ أَبِي كَثِيرٍ، عَنْ أَبِي سَلَمَةَ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ
> قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ مَنْ أَمْسَكَ كَلْبًا
> فَإِنَّهُ يَنْقُصُ مِنْ عَمَلِهِ كُلَّ يَوْمٍ قِيرَاطٌ إِلاَّ كَلْبَ
> حَرْثٍ أَوْ مَاشِيَةٍ‏"‏ ‏.‏     Abu Huraira (Allah be pleased with
> him) reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying:  He who kept a dog
> would lose out of his deeds equal to **one qirat every day**. except
> (one kept) for watching the field or herd.
>
> [Sahih Muslim, 1575 c In-Book Reference: Book 22, Hadith 71 USC-MSA
> web (English) reference: Book 10, Hadith 3824 (deprecated numbering
> scheme)]
>
> [4]
>
> حَدَّثَنَا قُتَيْبَةُ بْنُ سَعِيدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الْوَاحِدِ، -
> يَعْنِي ابْنَ زِيَادٍ - عَنْ إِسْمَاعِيلَ، بْنِ سُمَيْعٍ حَدَّثَنَا
> أَبُو رَزِينٍ، قَالَ سَمِعْتُ أَبَا هُرَيْرَةَ، يَقُولُ قَالَ رَسُولُ
> اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ مَنِ اتَّخَذَ كَلْبًا لَيْسَ بِكَلْبِ
> صَيْدٍ وَلاَ غَنَمٍ نَقَصَ مِنْ عَمَلِهِ كُلَّ يَوْمٍ قِيرَاطٌ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
> Abu Huraira (Allah be pleased with him) reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)
> as saying:  He who kept a dog, but not meant for hunting or watching
> the herd, would lose **one qirat of reward every day**.
>
> [Sahih Muslim, 1575 (f)]

And so on and on......

Now the question is, your neighbour is keeping a dog, *will you be held accountable for that*? It's funny because if we are not blamed for Adam's (as) fault how come we be held accountable for someone's fault except for our own deeds! And In your case definitely it’s not your wrong doing and Insh-Allah you will not be held accountable for this as you have a separate basement suite with a separate entrance and not having any intention to keep/treat this dog like the landlord. So don't be panicked.
As Allah 'azzawajal says in The glorious Qur'aan:-

> وَلَا تَزِرُ وَازِرَةٌ وِزْرَ أُخْرَىٰۚ وَإِن تَدْعُ مُثْقَلَةٌ إِلَىٰ
> حِمْلِهَا لَا يُحْمَلْ مِنْهُ شَىْءٌ وَلَوْ كَانَ ذَا قُرْبَىٰٓۗ
> إِنَّمَا تُنذِرُ ٱلَّذِينَ يَخْشَوْنَ رَبَّهُم بِٱلْغَيْبِ
> وَأَقَامُوا۟ ٱلصَّلَوٰةَۚ وَمَن تَزَكَّىٰ فَإِنَّمَا يَتَزَكَّىٰ
> لِنَفْسِهِۦۚ وَإِلَى ٱللَّهِ ٱلْمَصِيرُ
>
> **No soul burdened with sin will bear the burden of another**. And if a sin-burdened soul cries for help with its burden, none of it will be
> carried—even by a close relative. You [O Prophet] can only warn those
> who stand in awe of their Lord without seeing Him [[This can also mean
> that they are in awe of their Lord as much in private as they are in
> public]] and establish prayer. Whoever purifies themselves, they only
> do so for their own good. And to Allah is the final return.[Fatir
> 35:18]

So, what we come to know is that keeping dog is prohibited in islam and if don't do something on your own you will not be questioned for that act.

**`Now let us learn some rulings on impurity of dogs:`**

**1/** **A dog itself is not impure**. ***The impurity is in its "Saliva"*** when it drinks from a our vessels. Okay, then how we should wash the utensils.....

Aahadith---->

> [1]
>
> وَحَدَّثَنِي عَلِيُّ بْنُ حُجْرٍ السَّعْدِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا عَلِيُّ بْنُ
> مُسْهِرٍ، أَخْبَرَنَا الأَعْمَشُ، عَنْ أَبِي رَزِينٍ، وَأَبِي، صَالِحٍ
> عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم
> ‏"‏ إِذَا وَلَغَ الْكَلْبُ فِي إِنَاءِ أَحَدِكُمْ فَلْيُرِقْهُ ثُمَّ
> لْيَغْسِلْهُ سَبْعَ مِرَارٍ ‏"‏ ‏.‏     Abu Huraira reported the
> Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) to have said:  When a dog licks a utensil
> belonging to any one of you, (the thing contained in it) should be
> thrown away and then (the utensil) should be washed seven times.
> [Sahih Muslim, 279a In-Book Reference: Book 2, Hadith 114 USC-MSA web
> (English) reference: Book 2, Hadith 546]    [2]
>
> "وَحَدَّثَنَا عُبَيْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ مُعَاذٍ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبِي،
> حَدَّثَنَا شُعْبَةُ، عَنْ أَبِي التَّيَّاحِ، سَمِعَ مُطَرِّفَ بْنَ
> عَبْدِ اللَّهِ، يُحَدِّثُ عَنِ ابْنِ الْمُغَفَّلِ، قَالَ أَمَرَ
> رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم بِقَتْلِ الْكِلاَبِ ثُمَّ قَالَ ‏"‏
> مَا بَالُهُمْ وَبَالُ الْكِلاَبِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ ثُمَّ رَخَّصَ فِي كَلْبِ
> الصَّيْدِ وَكَلْبِ الْغَنَمِ وَقَالَ ‏"‏ إِذَا وَلَغَ الْكَلْبُ فِي
> الإِنَاءِ فَاغْسِلُوهُ سَبْعَ مَرَّاتٍ وَعَفِّرُوهُ الثَّامِنَةَ فِي
> التُّرَابِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏"     Ibn Mughaffal reported:  The Messenger of
> Allah (ﷺ) ordered killing of the dogs, and then said: What about them,
> i. e. about other dogs? and then granted concession (to keep) the dog
> for hunting and the dog for (the security) of the herd, and said: When
> the dog licks the utensil, wash it seven times, and rub it with earth
> the eighth time.  [Sahih Muslim, 280a In-Book Reference: Book 2,
> Hadith 119 USC-MSA web (English) reference: Book 2, Hadith 551
> (deprecated numbering scheme)]
>
> [3]
>
> أَخْبَرَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عَبْدِ الأَعْلَى الصَّنْعَانِيُّ، قَالَ
> حَدَّثَنَا خَالِدٌ، حَدَّثَنَا شُعْبَةُ، عَنْ أَبِي التَّيَّاحِ، قَالَ
> سَمِعْتُ مُطَرِّفًا، عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ الْمُغَفَّلِ، أَنَّ
> رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم أَمَرَ بِقَتْلِ الْكِلاَبِ
> وَرَخَّصَ فِي كَلْبِ الصَّيْدِ وَالْغَنَمِ وَقَالَ ‏"‏ إِذَا وَلَغَ
> الْكَلْبُ فِي الإِنَاءِ فَاغْسِلُوهُ سَبْعَ مَرَّاتٍ وَعَفِّرُوهُ
> الثَّامِنَةَ بِالتُّرَابِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏     It was narrated from 'Abdullah
> bin Al-Mughaffal that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) commanded that dogs
> be killed, but he made an exception for hunting dogs and sheepdogs and
> said:  "If a dog licks a vessel then wash it seven times, and rub it
> the eighth time with dust."  [Sunan an-Nasa'i, 67 In-Book Reference:
> Book 1, Hadith 67 English Reference: Vol.1, Book 1,Hadith 67]
>
> [4]
>
> "أَخْبَرَنَا عَمْرُو بْنُ يَزِيدَ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا بَهْزُ بْنُ
> أَسَدٍ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا شُعْبَةُ، عَنْ أَبِي التَّيَّاحِ، يَزِيدَ
> بْنِ حُمَيْدٍ قَالَ سَمِعْتُ مُطَرِّفًا، يُحَدِّثُ عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ
> بْنِ مُغَفَّلٍ، قَالَ أَمَرَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم
> بِقَتْلِ الْكِلاَبِ قَالَ ‏"‏ مَا بَالُهُمْ وَبَالُ الْكِلاَبِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
> قَالَ وَرَخَّصَ فِي كَلْبِ الصَّيْدِ وَكَلْبِ الْغَنَمِ وَقَالَ ‏"‏
> إِذَا وَلَغَ الْكَلْبُ فِي الإِنَاءِ فَاغْسِلُوهُ سَبْعَ مَرَّاتٍ
> وَعَفِّرُوا الثَّامِنَةَ بِالتُّرَابِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ خَالَفَهُ أَبُو
> هُرَيْرَةَ فَقَالَ إِحْدَاهُنَّ بِالتُّرَابِ ‏.‏"     It was narrated
> that 'Abdullah bin Mughaffal said:  "The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)
> commanded that dogs be killed. He said: 'What do they have to do with
> dogs?' And he granted a concession regarding hunting dogs and
> sheepdogs. And he said: 'If a dog licks a vessel, wash it seven times,
> and rub it the eighth time with dust.' Abu Hurairah differed from him
> and said: 'Rub it one time with dust.'"  [Sunan an-Nasa'i, 337 In-Book
> Reference: Book 2, Hadith 13 English Reference: Vol. 1, Book 2, Hadith
> 338]

And so on and on....

Now we know how to wash the vessels, if a dog drinks from a vessel, then the owner of this vessel has to throw away the thing contained in it and ***wash it seven times with water and lastly wash it with soil***.

**2/** As for kissing/touching a dog
the most correct view is that
(**Quoted**) :- "If the 'Wetness' of the dog’s hair gets onto one’s garment or body, that does not make it najis.” (*Majmu’ al-Fatawa*, 21/530)

In conclusion I want to say that you shouldn’t let the shaytan to play with your mind (i.e. "OCD"-- search on Youtube for this OCD issue to learn more about it from 'Sheikh Assim Al Hakeem').

Comment: JazakAllahu Khairan brother!